# ASP.NET MVC application name change not reflected even though I changed it in all the places

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging

I have been working on a web application and in the half way down the application, I have changed the name of my project but that is not being reflected even though I changed it in all the places. Like when I try to watch how my web site is working through command prompt, I am able to see it working only with old name. As I entered the new changed name, it just threw me site not found error. To explain it more clearly, I am including a screenshot

[image]

In the screenshot my new project name is WhiteBoard and the old one was SignalRDemo.

May I know where I am making a mistake.

Comment: I think you ahve to change the actual site name, not just the project name. You should be able to change it in the Web tab of your project as well.

Comment: Worked Fine when I changed the Assembly Name in the project properties

Comment: But that is just the name of the output assembly and isn't related to the actual virtual directory name. Initially I think it takes the web apps directory name which is usually the project's name which is usually the assembly output's name.